# Set value for property name for all subclasses using Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reflection

so i have a property CreatedOn and ModifiedOn
that exsist on most of my classes

and sometimes i need to check in a object, if there is a date that has not been set yet

so i use this method

```
    public void setDateTimeIfNotSet(object p)
    {
        if (p == null) return;
        Type t = p.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if ((info.Name == "CreatedOn" || info.Name == "ModifiedOn") && info.CanWrite && (DateTime)info.GetValue(p,null) == default(DateTime))
            {
                info.SetValue(p, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

It work fine but only for the first level properties 
like `object.ModifiedOn`

but i need it to go trough all sub objects
like

```
object.subobject.ModifiedOn
object.subobject2.ModifiedOn
object.subobject.subsubobject.ModifiedOn
```

Comment: first thing i will suggest is derive all your class with one `interface`. ( even blank interface will work for you) those are going to be in parent child child child child relationship then its easy to use that. because calling recursive on all the properties is not a good idea. if you can do that i can suggest a way. but without that its not good to loop thorough all th properies.

Comment: i cant change the class i dont have access to that

Comment: keep in mind that's not something that's done a lot its only used ones in a while for a check

Comment: as you dont have source code but can you please check if all your classes like subobject, subobject2, subsubobject are derived from one interface or parent base entity.   dont say its derived from `object` class. :D

Comment: no its not and i only have access to add a small thing

Comment: if ur requirement of creating the created by updated by pattern mean fill these field when saving EF changes then check the one answer given by @venerik.. its what i have also used. but its for when EF save changes but you want normally let me know, i will try that too

Comment: that would be gr8 the problem is that the project is using EF4 and its database first so the models keep getting drops and recreated, is there a way for me to make sure that the code on save will not get lost?

Comment: no.. u can put this savechnges method in TT file. so even if u save the Edmx file it will create the same code snippet in ur context.cs file. no need to worry about that part.

Answer (score 4):

This is not really an answer to your question but might be a solution for your problem.

Are you sure you want to set those properties using reflection? Why don't you make sure all classes get those properties set when saving to the database using Entity Frameworks `ChangeTracker`  on `DbContext`.

You can do that by overriding `SaveChanges` of your context:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

    foreach(var entry in entries)
    {
        if(entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        else 
        {
            entry.Property("ModifiedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: that would be gr8 the problem is that the project is using EF4 and its database first so the models keep getting drops and recreated, is there a way for me to make sure that the code on save will not get lost?

Comment: this is the change you need to do in you EDMX > context file.  then everytime you will save it will code for you.  no need to worry about.  you have to copy paste this overwrite SaveChanges method in TT files.

Comment: i will check it out now

Comment: only thing u need to correct in about code is you need to check if property "CreateOn" "ModifiedOn" exist. as in above code he just showed the way to go.. not the destination.

Answer (score 2):

if you really wanted to use loop and handle that.. then try this..

```
public static void SetDateTimeIfNotSet(object p)
{
    Type t = p.GetType();
    t.GetProperties()
        .Where(c=>c.PropertyType.IsClass || c.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        .ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
        object child = c.GetValue(p);

        if (c.PropertyType == typeof (DateTime))
        {
            if(string.Equals(c.Name, "CreatedOn"))
            if((DateTime)child == default(DateTime))
            c.SetValue(p, DateTime.Now);
        }
        else
        {                    
            if(child!=null)
                SetDateTimeIfNotSet(c.GetValue(p));
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1JycJ2

Comment: yup im checking it now

Comment: i tested here and its working fine.  let me give u the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use recursion?

```
void Method(Type t)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in t.GetProperties())
    {
        if ((info.Name == "CreatedOn" || info.Name == "ModifiedOn") && info.CanWrite && (DateTime)info.GetValue(p,null) == default(DateTime))
        {
            info.SetValue(p, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
        }
        Method(info.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

This code wasn't tested, so use at your own risk.

Comment: hahaha.. this is what i asked OP thats its not good to loop through all the properties.. sorry to say but will raise lot of issue.  and performance wise its toooo bad..

Comment: @DeepakSharma I never said it was good to recursively loop through all nested properties. The OP asked a question (he/she didn't ask for a solution with the best performance) and I answered it.

Comment: thats what i was looking for, i will test it and see how quick it is,